# Keras error: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (256326, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I was trying to modeling multiple-output dnn. also using kaggle creditcard [data](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud). cause I was just trying to test, my code learn from only three dimensions.

my code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
temp = []
for x in X_train:
    temp.append(x[:3])
X_train = temp
temp = []
for x in X_test:
    temp.append(x[:3])
X_test = temp

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 3))
x = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
a_prediction = layers.Dense(1, name='a')(x)
b_prediction = layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax', name='b')(x)
c_prediction = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='c')(x)
model = Model(inputs, [a_prediction, b_prediction, c_prediction])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'a': mean_squared_error, 'b': categorical_crossentropy, 'c': binary_crossentropy}, loss_weights={'a': 0.25, 'b': 1., 'c': 10.})

model.fit(X_train, {'a': Y_train, 'b': Y_train, 'c': Y_train}, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
```

error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Develop/PycharmProjects/reinforcement recommandation system/test2.py", line 44, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, {'a': Y_train, 'b': Y_train, 'c': Y_train}, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
  File "C:\Users\Develop\PycharmProjects\reinforcement recommandation system\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1089, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Develop\PycharmProjects\reinforcement recommandation system\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 757, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Develop\PycharmProjects\reinforcement recommandation system\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 131, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (256326, 3)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape parameter for the Input layer should not include the batch size ([link to doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input)). Switching that line to `inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, ))` should solve your issue.

In future, you can use the `model.summary()` method to see the internal names of your layers and the expected output shape of each. For **your current code** the following is printed:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, None, 3)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, None, 16)     64          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, None, 20)     340         dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, None, 20)     0           dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, None, 16)     336         dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
a (Dense)                       (None, None, 1)      17          dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
b (Dense)                       (None, None, 16)     272         dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
c (Dense)                       (None, None, 1)      17          dense_3[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,046
Trainable params: 1,046
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

We can see that the input layer (`input_1`, the same as mentioned in the stack trace) incorrectly has three dimensions.